# Deploying Qt application - Didn't find entry procedure

Tags: c++, qt, release

I have started learning Qt recently and I wanted to deploy my application. I built my project in release version and copied necessary .dll's to .exe directory, but when I try to double-click my application file, I get a message box saying that entry procedure `_ZNK10QJsonValue8toStringEv` couldn't be found in app.exe library.

I'm begginer with Qt and I have no clue how to fix that. Thank you for all the responses!

I have copied all the libraries from Qt's bin folder - still getting the same error.

Comment: This means you have a mismatch in your dlls.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "necessary .dll's"? 2. Did you read [Deploying Qt Applications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html) ? Esspecialy [for Windows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

Comment: @mvidelgauz I have run `windeployqt` tool.

Comment: Recheck them (your dlls)

Comment: The windeployqt tool isn't magic. It can't read your mind. You still need to understand what's in the deployed folder, and what might be missing.

Comment: @KubaOber i know it. I copied some libraries by myself, but still can't find the one which will fix my problem. JSON support should be in QtCore, but even though I have that in my exe directory I still get that error.

Comment: ***I copied some libraries by myself*** Did you get them from the same Qt binaries for the same compiler version that you are using for your application?

Comment: @drescherjm i found out that despite i have Qt 5.6 in my PATH variable, Qt Creator was using Qt 5.7. Everything is working now.